# install latest version of package FactoMineR for R version 3.3

Tags: r

I have to get the latest version of the R package FactoMineR working for R version 3.3. So I tried:

```
install.packages('FactoMineR',repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')
```

but I get:

```
Error in readRDS(file) :
  cannot read workspace version 3 written by R 3.6.1; need R 3.5.0 or newer
In addition: Warning message:
package 'FactoMineR' is not available (for R version 3.3.3)
Error in readRDS(file) :
  cannot read workspace version 3 written by R 3.6.1; need R 3.5.0 or newer
> version
```

any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You probably need to update R.

Comment: I cant for the production system ...

Comment: The latest version of that package requires R version ≥ 3.5.0, clearly listed as a dependency on CRAN.